# How can I fix Google Speech Recotnition misbehaving: When it starts SR it freezes

Tags: google-now, voice-recognition

**Symptoms**

If I launch Google Now it seems OK (I can scroll the list of Cards, etc.) but if  speak "google" it does not start voice recognition and it freezes (can't scroll the 'cards' down, etc.) or simply exits.
If I manually touch the mic, it sometimes works but usually it just exits without doing anything.
Google Chrome search (entering search term as text) works fine.
Google Speech Recognition freezes similarly in other apps when I choose the Mic from the keyboard (I.e., SR instead of keyboard for text entry)

**Update**:
*This seems to be a general problem with Speech Recognition. SR isn't working in any other app I tried it with.*

**What I've tried:**

- Verified that Bluetooth is disabled.
- Factory Reset
- Cleared all Cache
- Updated Google Now
- Verified the Settings>Voice>Hotword ("google') detection is enabled.
- cleared the App Data (not just the Cache) (for Google Search)
- I'm going to try to figure out how to disable the offline Speech Recognition next.

**Any other suggestions?**

Motorola Droid Razr M, Android 4.1.2